# Visual Studio 2013 Apache Cordova App gives connect ETIMEDOUT Error

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, office365, visual-studio-cordova

I am using Visual Studio 2013 update 5 with Tools for Apache Cordova Feature .
I tried to build a Simple App from this link

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ocarpen/2015/03/21/sharepoint-online-apache-cordova-et-winjs-crer-des-apps-mobiles-dentreprise-multi-devices/

Currently I have completed the App till 4th Section in that page(Authentication to Office 365 and SharePoint Online)

The thing is when i am building the App , it is giving "connect ETIMEDOUT " error.

[image]

I Have no proxy settings. Please Help .

Comment: try to clear cache like this in visual studio `Tools --> Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova` now click on `clear cordova cache`

Comment: Could you please try it with VS2015? Tools for Apache Cordova served only as "Technique Preview" in VS2013 and it has been migrated to VS2015. SO VS2015 is the only official version of TACO.